# Upload button appears when not called- but i have 2 instances

Tags: fine-uploader

I have created 2 instances of S3 uploader in a page and i have given them different div names.
One of the instances is set to auto upload and the other is set to manual upload with edit file names set.

However the instance with auto upload is pulling the upload button from the other instance as well. It sits there and does nothing because the upload works as intended- automatically. Other than this rogue button both forms work as i want.

This is the div for the button but i only have it in one instance

```html
<div id="triggerUpload-feeds" class="qq-upload-button start-upload" style="margin-top: 10px;cursor:pointer;">Upload</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry I just dont understand how to paste code into this site and make it appear, i am not a dev, just a hack really I guess

Comment: There is most likely an error in your code, so you'll need to show it to receive further help.  The best way to do this may be to paste your JavaScript and HTML into http://jsbin.com/ and include the link in your question.

Comment: ok, i dont wish to register another site for one problem when i dont know how to use the site. I might just ask my dev to help. Thanks anyway

Comment: No need to register, just paste your code and copy the link.  But your best bet is likely to pass this off to a developer.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/daligobiwizo/1/edit

Comment: they are in sliding divs btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fine Uploader UI looks for a template in the document with an ID of "qq-template".  Therefore, both uploaders are being constructed from the same template.  If you want multiple uploaders on the same page that pull from different templates, you'll need to ensure you define multiple templates in your markup, each with a different ID.  You'll then need to reference the appropriate template when you construct each Fine Uploader UI instance.

For example:

```html
<script type="text/template" id="qq-template1">
<!-- template markup here -->
</script>
```

```html
<script type="text/template" id="qq-template2">
<!-- template markup here -->
</script>
```

```js
<script>
var uploader1 = new qq.FineUploader({
    template: 'qq-template1'
});

var uploader2 = new qq.FineUploader({
    template: 'qq-template2'
});
</script>
```

For more info, see the [templating/styling feature page in the docs](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/styling.html).

Comment: i copied this but template 2 is not loading. Where do i add the bottom script in page?

Comment: This is solved, templates had to go into the head. And the bottom script threw me off as i am using JQuery and that is not for JQuery